# Service Worker 'install' is not working on iOS, but works on Android

Tags: android, ios, caching, installation, service-worker

I have a strange situation and need some help - was unable to find any information about it specifically.

So I am trying to cache a website offline using service workers. I have it working on windows desktop and android Chrome. However, on iOS iPhone 12.1.2 it does not work. 
I've had the iPhone on debug and was able to see the console. 
Apparently there are no errors and the service worker is registering.
See code below:

JS

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log('Service Worker supported')
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register('../sw_cache.js')
            .then(function(reg){
                console.log('Service Worker: Registered')
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log('Service Worker: Error '+err)
            })
    })
}
```

So all that seems to work, I can see the console log on iOS debug. But for some reason the sw_cache.js file does not respond. I tried putting a console log in there and even a try catch.

See my install event here:

sw_cache.js

```
var cacheName = 'v1';

var cacheAssets = [... list of assets ... ]

self.addEventListener('install', function(e){
    console.log('Service Worker: Installed');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches
            .open(cacheName)
            .then(function(cache){
                console.log('Service Worker: Caching Files');
                cache.addAll(cacheAssets)
            })
            .then(function(){
                self.skipWaiting();
            })
    )
})

// Call Activate Event
self.addEventListener('activate', function(e){
    console.log('Service Worker: Activated');
    // Remove unwanted caches
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames){
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(function(cache){
                    if (cache !== cacheName){
                        console.log('Service Worker: Clearing Old Cache');
                        return caches.delete(cache);
                    }
                })
            )
        })
    );
})

// Call Fetch Event
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request));
});
```

[Screenshot - Proof of service worker registering on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spgCb.png)

Folder structure:
[Example of my folder structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoLdt.png)
All my paths are relative (if that has anything to do with anything?)

Does anyone know why it would work for Android and not iOS? Is there something wrong with what I have written?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to confirm, which version of iOS are you testing?

Comment: iOS iPhone 12.1.2